# Launch screen storyboard constraints in iOS Universal app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, swift2

I'm working on a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file for an iOS Universal app in Xcode 7.3.

I must use only constraints defined in storyboard, because the launch screen will be shown before the app will be loaded (can't configure constraints programmatically in a `UIViewController` subclass).

The background image in the main `UIViewController` has

- aspect-ratio (`3456:2592`),
- center vertically and
- center horizontally constraints.

I'm trying to obtain the following conditions:

- maintain the background image aspect-ratio,
- activate `backgroundImageView.Top = containerView.Top` when ***screen width <= screen height***
  [image]
- activate `backgroundImageView.Leading = containerView.Leading - 20` when ***screen width > screen height***
  [image]

The problem is that storyboard constraint definition by size classes is not powerful enough to express conditions like ***screen width >/<= screen height*** (e.g.: an iPad Air Fullscreen has always regular width and height, but ***screen width < screen height*** in portrait mode and ***screen width > screen height*** in landscape mode).

I tried also to define the background image asset set by device, but it allows only to specify iPhone/iPad x1, x2 and x3 versions of the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need auto-layout for this. Make the UIImageView fill the whole screen, then select the Aspect Fill mode for the background UIImageView.

[image: Select "Aspect Fill" mode]

Result:

[image]

Note that the background image (1) keeps the aspect ratio, (2) centered horizontally and vertically, and (3) automatically scale up to fit the longest axis.

Comment: Hi, any recommended image size?

Comment: @FernandoReynoso If you want crisp edge, make it a square like 2001×2001 (at 3x for iPhone 7). But if the background is photographic which doesn't need crisp edge, the image size doesn't really matter as long as it isn't too small. Just let your graphic designer make the choice.